# kubernetes logs don't show timestamp

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

`$ microk8s kubectl logs --timestamps --prefix lh-detector-54944c4495-7hd65`

```
Error from server (BadRequest): container "lh-detector" in pod "lh-detector-54944c4495-7hd65" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

no timestamps, no prefix. Tried to put arguments after pod name - as in reference - no difference. Similarly `--since` seem to have no effect.

Comment: Seems like the container didn't start. It blocks on pulling image. You can try `kubectl describe` the pod to see the information.

Comment: Yes but there is no timestamp in both cases, which would be nice to have, especially given the option is present.

Comment: `kubectl describe` shows how long ago the pod event occurred. If you want to get the exact time, you can get `lastTransitionTime` from `kubectl get pod ... -o yaml`.